# Notify user to save the changes when they change the tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to notify the user to save changes (only if they do not click the save button) before they leave the tab. I found many examples on dirty page, jquery, onbeforeunload etc but every example notifies the user before they leave the page where as I want to notify before they change or move to other tab present in the navbar of the same page. Please help me out

Comment: This is not possible. Javascript receives no event when a user switches between active tabs.

Comment: Have a click/focus handler for the tabs that you have on your page. Check to see if the data was saved when a tab that is not equal to the one that they are currently on is clicked/focused. If you are talking about when the user switches browser tabs, $(window).on("blur", function () { alert("why are you leaving?");}); will alert the user whenever they try to switch browser tabs

Comment: maybe define a variable that becomes true when a user saves, and a function that checks that variables value every time a new tab is clicked. you would just need to be careful about resetting it correctly or have a separate variable for each tab (but you would still want resets probably, because they may, within the same session, navigate back to that tab and add more information - and you don't want the old value of it already being saved to still exist in that case)

Comment: $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
 });
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

  if ($scope.needToConfirm == true) {

   if (confirm("You forgot to save!!")) {
    event.preventDefault();
   }
  }

 }); This worked for me Thanq all

Answer (score 0):

Very basic, and it may not meet your needs, but it's *kind of* possible to achieve.

This method just detects the `blur` and `focus` events of `window`. Downside, it will also fire the alert when they click **anywhere** outside of the window. It's probably as close as you'll get to detecting tab changes unfortunately.

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    //They are staying on the page
    console.log("You've chocen to stay")
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    //They're leaving the tab
    alert("Sure you don't want to stay?");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyKzzK)

Comment: $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
 });
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

  if ($scope.needToConfirm == true) {

   if (confirm("You forgot to save!!")) {
    event.preventDefault();
   }
  }

 }); This worked for me Thanq all